# Declarative pipeline to check the build step = Failure then trigger next build step, but not fail the job.

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to fail a build step in Jenkinsfile with failed results = failure. Once the step is failed it triggers my rollback job.  Tried many different things, but had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Git Checkout') {
         steps {
           script {
           git 'somegit-repo'
           sh'''
           mvn package
           '''
           echo currentBuild.result
           catchError {
           build 'rollback'
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a shell script and with `exit 1` statement
e.g.

```
sh "exit 1"
```

Or you can use error step

```
error('Failing build because...')
```

See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#error-error-signal

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try` `catch` block

```
    node {

       stage("Run scripts") {

           try {
              <some command/script> 
           } catch (error) {
              <rollback command/script>
           }

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. This seems to work!

```
   stages {
      stage("some test") {
        steps{ 
          script {
             git 'mygitrepo.git'
           try {
            sh''' mvn test '''
           } catch (error) {
          script {
           def job = build job: 'rollback-job'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [cleaning and notifications](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/) page

You can do a `post` step and get rid of all the try/catch stuff and get a cleaner Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('No-op') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo 'One way or another, I have finished'
            deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
        }
        success {
            echo 'I succeeeded!'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'I am unstable :/'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
        }
        changed {
            echo 'Things were different before...'
        }
    }
}
```